# geom_label: change the thickness of the shape outline

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

With `geom_label` instead of `geom_text`, my labels get a background shape with a black outline shape. I know I can control the text size with `size` argument, but this doesn't affect the border. Is it possible to control the thickness of this black outline border?

Like having a result similar to the plot on the right hand side:

[image]

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(rownames_to_column(mtcars, "name")) + geom_label(aes(label=name, x=mpg, y=hp), size=4)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `label.size` parameter can be set per-layer. It is not an aesthetic in the sense that you can map data to this parameter, so splitting the thin and thick outlined text in different layers seems the only sensible option.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(rownames_to_column(mtcars, "name")) + 
  geom_label(data = ~ tail(.x, -4), 
             aes(label=name, x=mpg, y=hp), 
             size=4, label.size = 0.25) +
  geom_label(data = ~ head(.x, 4), 
             aes(label=name, x=mpg, y=hp), 
             size=4, label.size = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks. indeed, i was hoping it would be an aesthetic but no as you say

Answer (score 1):

The option you need is `geom_label(label.size = n)`

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(rownames_to_column(mtcars, "name")) + 
  geom_label(aes(label = name, x = mpg, y = hp), 
             size = 4, 
             label.size = 2)
```

[image]